# RESTful web services and RESTful API

Tags: json, rest, restful-architecture

i am creatng a backend that provides JSON to an angularJS front end which is recieves JSON by $resource. Would this be known as a RESTFul API or as a restful web service. I am unsure of what the difference is between the 2 terms are or can they be used interchangeably? Could someone explain the difference between restful api and restful web service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're basically the same. ReST is an architectural style for distributed applications. Most of the time Restful applications consist of web-pages consuming web-services or web-services consuming other web-services but they don't have to be web-based. The important aspects being the use of a uniform API (usually http) and not maintaining shared state between the client and server.

If you're developing a ReSTful web-service then you're developing a ReSTful API over http (or https).